Domain Specific Hashing Algorithm
I have an application that takes a set of genetic variations from a test result and maps them to a known set of haplotypes. I have the mapping process worked out, but I want a very fast way of looking up stored results. We are storing now in a string of VariantId (value can be 1 - 8,000) and TestResult (value can be 1 - 20) pairs. There can be up to 150 variant/result pairs.
The current code to create the lookup string is
select  PID,
    v.GeneId,
    STRING_AGG(convert(nvarchar(8),vr.VariantId) + ':' + convert(nvarchar(8), vr.TestResult), ';') 
    Within Group (Order by vr.VariantId ) GeneResults

Which produces strings like this:
20:1;25:2;50:5;215:2;662:2;739:8;3704:8;6212:2;6384:8;6542:2;6543:2;6546:2;6548:2;6562:1;6563:1

I am pretty sure that there would be a way of fitting these within a 64-bit integer. Simple addition would not work because there is the potential that a different pair of variantIds could add to the same number but potentially some combination of the order in the sequence would.
Is there a common algorithm to resolve this? Ideally, could something be implemented in SQL for the runtime lookup?
Thanks for any insight that you might have,
Don Rule
Translational Software
